# Multiple transactions insert with same index-key cause mysql InnoDB deadlock

Tags: mysql, multithreading, innodb, database-deadlocks

From mysql manual book(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locks-set.html)
,there is a deadlock scenario about insert statement:

*Suppose that an InnoDB table t1 has the following structure:*

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (i INT, PRIMARY KEY (i)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

*Now suppose that three sessions perform the following operations in order:*

*Session 1:*

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

*Session 2:*

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

*Session 3:*

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1);
```

*Session 1:*

```
ROLLBACK;
```

*The first operation by session 1 acquires an exclusive lock for the row. The operations by sessions 2 and 3 both result in a duplicate-key error and they both request a shared lock for the row. When session 1 rolls back, it releases its exclusive lock on the row and the queued shared lock requests for sessions 2 and 3 are granted. At this point, sessions 2 and 3 deadlock: Neither can acquire an exclusive lock for the row because of the shared lock held by the other.*

Now a big wondering come out,why not sessions 2 and 3 request a **exclusive lock** when duplicate-key error occurs,this way,sessions 2 and 3 can queued and wait for **exclusive lock** to realse and they can both get processed one by one

Comment: Interesting question.  But I doubt if any implementers are on this forum -- they would need to address it.

Comment: yes you're right,I'll try this question at mysql forums